# open location coordinates in my flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, location, deep-linking

I want to open google maps location link in my flutter app and retrieve the latitude and longitude from the link and perform some action on it like getting directions to this coordinates

**For Example** when I press the link : https://www.google.com/maps?q=45.100083,96.2000699&z=17&hl=en

it shows my app between the options just like this :
[image: I need to show my apps between these links]

**note** : I looked for some solutions like uni_links package but I couldn't get it right .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) in your `pubspec.yaml` for direct link open maps in your smartphone with **LatLng** value in your url_launcher method

```
void _launchShareLocUrl() async {
  final url =
      'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=${data.latitude},${data.longitude}';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

and you can call method name in `onPressed:` button like this example

```
TextButton(
      onPressed: () => _launchShareLocUrl(), child: Text("Maps")),
```

[image]

Comment: you didn't get me right

Comment: i need when i press the google maps location link to open it in my app

Comment: oh I see, have you try this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking